# How to get this washed out look in lightroom

Tags: post-processing, portrait, lightroom-4

How to get this low contrast washed flared look for portraits in lightroom

https://www.flickr.com/photos/emsoto/

Comment: It's always a bit hard to tell with these questions, but I think my answer to the earlier question I linked should cover this. Let me know if it doesn't, and add more details, please. (Thank you very much for describing the effect rather than just linking!)

Comment: PS: it's possible that the next batch of photos that photographer adds to her photo stream on Flickr will have a totally different look. It's better to link to a few specific examples which strongly exemplify the effect.

Comment: Looks like mostly a raised black level, some desaturation, and a color shift towards yellow.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Clarity slider but go negative on it and that will soften the look. However that will apply it to the whole image, whereas this looks like it was done selectively (one way in camera would be to apply vaseline to a clear filter).

To replicate that, use the Adjustment Brush to paint various areas you want to soften and then apply the Negative Clarity. Play with a few of the other Adjustment Brush sliders to change exposure and saturation to refine.